# Formula ruining totals

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have created a matrix, which shows the salary of employees, but is able to have realized values for the month already closed and budget values for the rest of the year. I've made the following code to make it work.

```
Rolling Salary = 
IF(
VALUE(SELECTEDVALUE('FilterTabel'[Month])) >= AVERAGE('Date'[Month]),
'MeasureTable'[Salary Realized],
'MeasureTable'[Salary Budget]
)
```

As you can see, i'm not a good coder and i "cheated" by taking an average for the date[month] as the average in january will always be 1 and so on.

The problem starts at the total. As the average of Date[Month] in the total is 6,5 it will show a summarization of Salary Budget in the first 6 months, and a summarization of Salary Realized in the last six months.

In the ideal world, i would have the total just summarizing the values of the row. So if i had chosen june and have 6 months of realized salaries and 6 months of budgetted salarys, it would give me the sum of those 12 months together.

Is anyone able to help me fix my problem?

Best Regards